# Check the username existing in the database Java netbeans

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I am writing a code to check the username availability in the database.

```
public boolean checkUsername(String u) {

        boolean userExists = false;

        try {
            String check = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_Name desc";

            pst = conn.prepareStatement(check);

            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            String usernamePool;

            if (rs.next()) {
                usernamePool = rs.getString("user_Name");//column name
                if (usernamePool.equals(u)) {
                    userExists = true;
                }
                if (userExists = true) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username already in use", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }

        return userExists;

    }
```

Every time i called this method it says username already in use i think the boolean value is always true why is that?

```
else if (checkUsername(signUpUsername.getText().toString())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Profile Created Failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

this is how i call the method

If someone can say what is wrong with is it will be very helpful

Comment: `if (userExists = true)` this is an assignment, you are assigning true value to the userExists in the if check, that is why it's always true, to compare it should be `if (userExists == true)` (double = sign) or simply `if (userExists)` as stated in the answer below

Comment: It doesn't work when i use that it will create the profile but before the it didn't create the profile but i always kept saying a match found @Coreggon

Answer (score 1):

```
if (userExists = true) {
```

has to be

```
if (userExists) {
```

Also, there is no need to iterate over all users. SQL supports a WHERE clause which you can use with prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection.

Here is your method as I'd write it (you can use the `connection` as global in your class, that's fine, but don't do it with the `statements` and `result sets`...):

```
public boolean checkUsername(String username) {

    boolean userExists = false;

    try {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        userExists = rs.next();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
    }

    return userExists;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i use that it will create the profile but before the it didn't create the profile but i always kept saying a match found

Comment: I edited my answer with the way I'd write it. That should work. If not, you're doing something else wrong. Please use your proper connection though! I just set it to null to have the method selection in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(userExists = true)
```

You used one equals symbol instead of two, which is the assignment operator not the equality operator. The assignment operator returns the value that was assigned, therefore it will always return true. Change the above line to:

```
if(userExists)
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i use that it will create the profile but before the it didn't create the profile but i always kept saying a match found